# Issue running KNative with MicroK8S on Multipass

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, knative, knative-serving, multipass

I'm trying to get KNative to be able to create services on my Multipass VM with MacOS as the host OS and I am using MicroK8S. I have DNS enabled and I am using metallb as my ingress controller. I have also changed Multipass to use hyperkit instead of VirtualBox. I don't know what's not been configured or missconfigured. The error I get when I try to create a new service is pasted below:

ubuntu@uncommon-javelin:~/sandbox/sessions/serverless_k8s/yaml$ kn service create nginx --image nginx --port 80
Error: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.serving.knative.dev": failed to call webhook: Post "https://webhook.knative-serving.svc:443/defaulting?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.152.183.167:443: connect: connection refused
Run 'kn --help' for usage

When I ping that IP, it times out. So it seems like that IP address is either locked down or doesn't exist. Port 443 is configured in my ingress-service.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  selector:
    name: nginx-ingress-microk8s
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
```

And here is what I have configured for metallb address pool

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
  annotations:
    metallb.univers.tf/address-pool: custom-addresspool
spec:
  selector:
    name: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

And here's another address-pool.yaml I have configured for my cluster, I'm pretty sure that I have either something networking misconfigured or I'm missing a configuration somewhere.

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: custom-addresspool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knative uses validating admission webhooks to ensure that the resources in the cluster are valid. It seems like the Knative webhooks are not running on your cluster, but the validatingwebhookconfiguration has been created, as has the service in front of the webhook (the IP in the error message is a ClusterIP of a Kubernetes service on your cluster).

I'd look at the webhook pods in the `knative-serving` namespace for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I had to go in and remove knative-serving and set it up again along with metallb and I got it working.